# C# - Comparing float values

Tags: c#, comparison

I have a little problem when trying to compare 2 float values.
In my project, every Game object has a .Score
Every .Score property has a float value between 0 and 10 with steps of 0.5
In minimumscoreId a float value of 0..11 is stored (0 is if the function is unused)
I iterate over every game to see if the score is higher than the selected score. But when I select 9 as minimumScore, It sais 9.5 < 9.5

What's  even more strange is that if I select 8, it gives me back the values of a game with a score of 9, another one with 9.5 and another one with 7.5 ...

I just really don't know where to look for this problem, I tried stopping and checking the values, but it just sais `if( 9.5 < 9.0 )` and it still goes into the if...

```
if (minimumScoreId > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < minimumScoreId; i++)
        {
            float score = ( ((Game)(games[i]) ).Score);
            if ( score < ( minimumScoreId + 1.0) )
            {
                //delete from a list (this works in other functions without the float thing)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to compare the score to minimumScore*Id*?

Comment: In your text you use `>` but in the code it is `<`. Could you be confusing the two?

Comment: BTW, your first `if` is redundant here - the `for` loop does not run if `minumumScoreId` is zero (or less).

Comment: I corrected the text, thanks.
@500-InternalServerError I corrected that in the code as well, thanks ;) and I'm sure I want to compare these two values, the "Id" is just to keep the name the same as the other filters. The value it gets comes out of a comboBox where the 0'th value is just a placeholder and all following ones are 1,2,3,...

Comment: I suspect your "delete from a list" code is not working as you expect.

Comment: @AndrewMorton may be on to something. If you are deleting from `games` at position `i` then you need to be iterating through it backwards.

Comment: I'd consider using integers internally and only converting to floating point for displaying.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (minimumScoreId > 0)
                {
                    filter = true;
                    int j = 1;
                    for (int i = 1; i < minimumScoreId; i++)
                    {
                        float score = (((Game)(games[i-1])).Score);
                        if (score < ((float)minimumScoreId + 0.0))
                        {
                            gamesUpdate.RemoveAt(j-1);
                            j--;
                        }
                        j++;
                    }
```

Thanks for the help everyone! The 2 last replies were also very helpful, I will make the iteration go backwards if I have extra time. At the moment I solved it this way, and it works.